# App Store からダウンロードした時にだけ、画像が表示されない

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

App Store にアプリをリリース後、本番のストアからそのアプリをダウンロードします。すると、アプリ内の一部の画像が正しく表示されず、ローディング画像 (Activity Indicator) がずっと表示される状況です。
アーカイブした時点でビルドした際は、正常に表示できていました。
（ Apple の審査も無事に通過しています）

ストアからダウンロードした場合にだけ発生する現象に頭を抱えています。

何かアドバイスなどいただければ幸いです。

**■ 使用した環境**

- XCode 6.1.1
- Objective-C

**■ 該当箇所の特徴**

- ある写真を一覧表示するUIがある
- コレクションビューを使用して、タイル状に画像を並べる
- タイル状に並んだ画像はAPIを叩いて一覧のURLを取得
- 取得したURLを元に画像をコレクションビュー内部に imageView として表示

**■ View の構成**

- collectionView の中に cell を配置
- cell の中には Activity Indicator が下になるように ImageView を配置
- 表示する際に、 SDWebImage を使用

実装はこんな感じ

```
 [imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageCacheMemoryOnly completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
    [UIView transitionWithView:weakImageView duration:0.4 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:nil completion:nil];
}];
```

順番に表示させるために `duration:0.4` を付けています。

タイル状の画像をタップすると、Navigation Controller で詳細にサムネイル画像を大きく表示。
一覧の画像の背景にはローディング画像 (Activity Indicator) があり、画像が表示されるまでにローディング画像が表示されます。

**■ 補足**

次の3つの端末で検証しましたがすべて同じ状況でした。 iPhone6,6+ 、 iPhone5S（すべて iOS 8.1 以上）ただし、 iPhone4S (iOS 7.0.2) だけは問題なく表示されました。

Comment: 発生する端末としない端末のコンソール出力に差はありますか？

Comment: APIを叩いた結果、表示のエラーは無く差異も見当たりませんでした。

Answer (score 3):

まずは再現性を上げたい所ですね。
「リリース後のアプリだけ」というのはやや考えにくいため、
お手元で（Debugではなく）Releaseビルドしたものを実機で試す、
もしくはAdHocを利用して実機で実行してみてはいかがでしょうか。

その手順で再現するのであれば、原因特定が遥かにやりやすくなるのではないかと思います。

Comment: Releaseビルドは既に試みておりますが上記の状況です。
AdHocを利用してテストフライト経由でインストールについては、未実施でしたのでこれから試してみたいと思います。